# OpenCV re-size image then apply filter

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to modify the code below to resize the image then read it. If i do this i get an error message.

```
sample = cv2.imread(sample)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Could anyone advise what i need to do to get this code to work please:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    path = self.files[idx]
    sample = Image.open(path)
    sample = sample.resize((512, 512))
    sample = cv2.imread(path)
  
    # set blue and green channels to 0

    sample[:, :, 0] = 0
    sample[:, :, 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you set the path correctly.

For instance: I want all my **.png** images in my directory.

- I would use `/*.png` tag to get all png's from the directory.

```
from glob import glob

image_files = glob("/Users/ahmettavli/Pictures/*png")
```

Second, you first read the image, then resize it.

```
from cv2 import imread
from cv2 import resize

img = imread(filename=path)
img = resize(src=img, dsize=(512, 512))
```

Here is the example:

```
from glob import glob
from cv2 import imread
from cv2 import resize


class ReadImages:
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.files[idx]
        img = imread(filename=path)
        img = resize(src=img, dsize=(512, 512))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_files = glob("/Users/ahmettavli/Pictures/*png")
    image_object = ReadImages(files=image_files)
    image_object.__getitem__(idx=0)
```

Output: